# How to change workout time effectively?

Tags: workout-routines

Due to my new job, which is 9 hours of sitting and staring at the computer from  10 AM to 7PM I am going to miss my usual 5 PM gym workout. I want to get started with StrongLift 5*5 again but do it in the morning for two days. Tuesday and Thursday 7.30 to 8.30 AM and Saturday 5 to 6 PM. Because I haven't done a workout in the mornings before I'd like to know about correct eating in the morning before and after workout, plus any additional tips you guys want to share. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regards to before the workout, you will want to eat something; the question is whether to eat a full breakfast or a smaller snack. The [Mayo Clinic](http://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-living/fitness/in-depth/exercise/art-20045506) recommends to leave enough time in the morning to finish your breakfast an hour before you begin your workout, and if that time allotment fits into your schedule, eat a normal to small sized breakfast. If you're waking up closer to 7AM, and don't have that free hour, eating something small like a granola bar, english muffin, or fruit will help you to avoid the feelings of sluggishness and queasiness that a large breakfast brings close to a workout. If you go the snack route, you can follow that up with another snack or small breakfast after your workout to help give your body energy for the day. If you have something now that you eat between the end of your workout and dinner, you will be fine to move that to the time between the end of your workout and work.

Now that you'll already have worked out by the time you get to work, you'll likely be more hungry throughout the day, and bringing in snacks can help with that. Whereas before you were timing your eating to be ready to workout at the end of the day, you'll now be ending work around dinner time, and so you'll have to figure out what works for you in terms of when to eat during the day.

Another difference with a morning workout is you'll feel the aftereffects (soreness, tiredness, etc.) while you are at work, and so you may want to structure your day in a way that allows you some breaks throughout to move around and stretch. I've found that taking a quick 5 minute walk and stretching every couple hours is extremely beneficial when trying to remain focused for long periods of time at work.

Lastly, adequate sleep will be of more importance now, both to ensure you have a successful workout and to make sure you don't sleep too late and miss it. You're used to working out at night, when you have the whole day to ward off those morning feelings of sleepiness. Especially at the beginning, its going to be more difficult to get yourself to the gym, and not sleeping enough only makes that harder. One thing I've found helpful is to prepare all your clothes and snacks for the next day the night before. Its far easier to wake up, eat, then workout, than to wake up, eat, make lunch, look for work clothes, look for workout clothes, make sure you didn't forget anything in your tired morning state, and *then* go to the gym.

Best of luck with the new job, its great that you're finding a way to keep up your routine with the new hours!